# function similar to head() for matrix

Tags: r, matrix, head

I am looking for a function in any package that can print matrix[1:5, 1:5]. `head()` is good for those that have few columns but not for a large matrix. I know I can create my own function for it but I am wondering if there is a function for it already.

Comment: `dplyr:::print.tbl_df` might be useful

Comment: `print.tbl_df` seems to work on a `width` that is number of characters, rather than number of columns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a function called `peek` in a package called `futile.matrix`.

```
library(futile.matrix)
m <- matrix(c(1,3,4,2, 5,10,11,2, 3,42,8,22, 23,15,3,8), ncol = 4)
peek(m, 4)
```

From the description of that function:

> "Peek is a simple utility to conveniently look at a portion of a
>   matrix. This is similar to head and tail but provides a 2-dimensional
>   slice instead of a complete row."